# Converting text/csv files to UTF-8 format in batch file

Tags: batch-file, encoding, utf-8, cmd

I am coding a batch file where WMIC command gives an output which is written to a temp file

```
WMIC /node:%%A Volume get systemname,caption,freespace,capacity > temp.txt
```

Temp file is generated but its encoding is **UCS-2 Little Endian.**

So, when I am trying to read the text file using for loop,

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%B in (temp.txt) do (
        echo %%B
    )
```

This doesnot displays any output because of its encoding format.

Once I convert this **Temp.txt** to UTF-8/ANSI format the for loop reads the Temp file.

Can I know how can I get the output of WMIC command in **UTF-8/ANSI** or if not how can I convert **UCS-2 Little Endian** to **UTF-8/ANSI**

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the output of the wmic to convert the file

```
WMIC /node:%%A Volume get systemname,caption,freespace,capacity | find /v "" > temp.txt
```

Or you can convert the file with the `type` command

```
WMIC ..... > temp1.txt
type temp1.txt > temp.txt
```

Or you can directly retrieve the information in the `for` loop

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (
    'wmic /node:%%A Volume get systemname^,caption^,freespace^,capacity'
) do echo %%a %%b %%c %%d
```

Comment: Thanks, second suggestion helped.