# Change file encoding from UTF16 to UTF8 in Batch

Tags: batch-file, utf-8

I have some CSV files which are in UTF16 Big Endian format. I need to write a batch script to convert it in UTF8.

Is it possible to do that without external programs, or with external programs that are shipped with the OS (and hence can always be expected to be there)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting text/csv files to UTF-8 format in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273926/converting-text-csv-files-to-utf-8-format-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Just replace the UTF-16 BE BOM with the UTF-8 BOM.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "csvfile=test.csv"

:: store current console codepage to var
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%I in ('chcp') do set "_codepage=%%I"
:: temporarily change console codepage to UTF-8
>NUL chcp 1252

<"%csvfile%" set /p "firstLine="

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
>fixed.csv echo(!firstLine:*ÿ=ï»¿!
endlocal

for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%I in ("%csvfile%") do (
    >>fixed.csv echo(%%I
)

:: restore console to original codepage
>NUL chcp %_codepage%

>NUL move /y fixed.csv "%csvfile%"

echo Fixed.

I'll leave it as an exercise for the O.P. to make this loop through multiple CSV files.
```

Comment: Thanks Rojo. But still there is some issue. After implementing your code I am facing this error: The system cannot write to the specified device.

Comment: @Arpit Probably a system code page issue.  I just added a few lines to change the code page to Western European Latin, fix the BOM, then change the code page back the way it was.  See if that fixes it.  If not, then I'm guessing the error is exactly what it says, that you don't have write permission to the file or directory you're trying to write to.